# Allow for zero-value in short-circuit evaluation

Tags: javascript

Short-circuit evaluation determines if the first value is falsey. If so, return the second value, as follows:

```
var x = y || z; // if y is falsey return z
```

Is there a way to disregard zero-values as being falsey when using short-circuit evaluation without resorting to if/else statements or ternary operators?

Comment: Don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

You could check first if `y` is unequal to zero and take the numerical value and get the result of the default of `z` for `y`.

```
x = +(y !== 0) && (y || z)
```

> How it works:
>
> ```
> expression              y          part result  result  comment
> ----------------------  ---------  -----------  ------  ----------------------------
> +(y !== 0) && (y || z)                                  complete expression
>
> +(y !== 0)              0          0            0       result found, omit next part
>                                                         because of falsy value
>
> +(y !== 0)              1          1                    check next part
> 1          && (y || z)             y            y       take y, omit default
>
> +(y !== 0)              undefined  1                    check next part 
> 1          && (y || z)             z            z       take z as default
> ```

```js
function x(y, z) {
    return +(y !== 0) && (y || z);
}

console.log(x(0, 42));           // 0
console.log(x(4, 42));           // 4
console.log(x(undefined, 42));   // 42
console.log(x(0, null));         // 0
console.log(x(4, null));         // 4
console.log(x(undefined, null)); // null
console.log(x(0, 0));            // 0
console.log(x(4, 0));            // 4
console.log(x(undefined, 0));    // 0
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may wrap your number into a Number object and check so;

```js
var x = new Number(0) || console.log("never gets printed");
console.log(parseInt(x));
//or
console.log(x.valueOf());
```

Comment: Nice condition-less answer. This seems to be what the OP was looking for.

Comment: but if you do `var x = new Number(null) || console.log("never gets printed");`, that will print `0` and `0` also instead of logging `"never gets printed"`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

If `z` is a number, you can maybe use a trick like this:

```
var x1 = Number(y===0 && '0' || y || z)
// or
var x2 = (y===0 && '0' || y || z)-0
```

```js
var z = -1;

var y = 42;
var x = y || z;
var x1 = Number(y===0 && '0' || y || z)
var x2 = (y===0 && '0' || y || z)-0
console.log('x:',x, '  x1:',x1, '  x2:',x2);

var y = 0;
var x = y || z;
var x1 = Number(y===0 && '0' || y || z)
var x2 = (y===0 && '0' || y || z)-0
console.log('x:',x, '  x1:',x1, '  x2:',x2);

var y = null;
var x = y || z;
var x1 = Number(y===0 && '0' || y || z)
var x2 = (y===0 && '0' || y || z)-0
console.log('x:',x, '  x1:',x1, '  x2:',x2);
```

**Original answer:**

Maybe simple way can work (3 equivalents)

```
var x = (y === 0) ? 0 : (y || z);
var x = (!y && y!==0) ? z : y;
```

```js
var z = 'Was falsey';

var y = 42;
var x = y || z;
var x1 = (y === 0) ? 0 : (y || z);
var x2 = (!y && y!==0) ? z : y;
console.log('x:',x, 'x1:',x1, 'x2:',x2);

var y = 0;
var x = y || z;
var x1 = (y === 0) ? 0 : (y || z);
var x2 = (!y && y!==0) ? z : y;
console.log('x:',x, 'x1:',x1, 'x2:',x2);

var y = null;
var x = y || z;
var x1 = (y === 0) ? 0 : (y || z);
var x2 = (!y && y!==0) ? z : y;
console.log('x:',x, 'x1:',x1, 'x2:',x2);
```

Comment: Op said no ternarys

Comment: Ah, you're right, my mistake; added sample without ternary so !

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: this uses a ternary operator, so if that's not what you're looking for, don't use this.*

Of course this is another simple way to do it:

```
var x = y || y==0?0:z;
```

> if `y` is truthy, then `x` is set to `y`
>
> if `y` is falsy, and `y==0`, then `x` is set to `0`
>
> if `y` is falsy, and `y!=0`, then `x` is set to `z`;

Comment: `? :` ternarys ?? he said without if or ternarys

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya True... but there are a very few ways to do this.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work as expected but it helped me somewhere so +1;
It should be `var x= y || (y==0?0:z);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) Javascript operator `~` to convert the `0` to `-1` (it inverts the bits of the number). As you can imagine it converts `-1` back to `0` and that would be the only possible falsey value. Common falsy objects like `undefined`, `NaN` or `''` would become truey, which might or might not be what you want.

Your code would then look like this:

```
var x = ~y || z;
```

- ~(-2) equals 1
- ~(-1) equals 0
- ~(-0) equals -1
- ~(0) equals -1
- ~(1) equals -2